# Reset connection to Url/Port - If no data has been received in the past N Minutes

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink application that connects to a Url/Port, I see with the restart strategy it allows to check if the connection is still open or not.

My query is... If a connection is open but no data has been received in the past 'N' Minutes I want to RESETthe connection

Currently setup the connection using the basic flink tutorials

```
    // set up the streaming execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val data_stream = env.socketTextStream(url, port, socket_stream_deliminator, socket_connection_retries)
                         .map(x => printInput(x))
                          .writeToSocket(url, port, new SimpleStringSchema())

    // execute program
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Scala API Skeleton")
```

Is there a function call or some included map to call to check if the connection has sent data in the past 'N' Minutes and if not reconnect.
How would I go about doing this

Comment: Why would You want to do this ?

Comment: I am streaming data from a bad link, every now and then the connection will either not give data but still open, or the connection will restart